# home networking issue - can't redirect wifi devices to website

Tags: networking, redirection, wireless-networking

First, I am an amateur when it comes to networking/routing. I have an Internet-accessible website on a home computer that I use to test html/javascript/etc. I have a domain name and a static IP from my ISP.  The network is currently set up like this:

*Smart/RG SR400ac* - this is the router/modem and connects to the outside Internet. The only device plugged into it with an ethernet cable is a *Netgear R6900P* router.

The Smart/RG uses 192.168.x.x, and the R6900P uses 10.0.x.x for internal addresses.

The Smart/RG forwards port 80 to the R6900P, which then forwards port 80 to the webserver. The webserver is plugged into the R6900P with an ethernet cable.

Both the Smart/RG and the R6900P have wifi.

If I try to access the website by domain name from outside of this network (public wifi, a wired computer at someone else's house, etc.) I can get to it with no issues.

If I try to access the website from ethernet-connected devices that are plugged into the R6900P, they can connect with no issues.

However, if I try to connect to the website using the wifi on either the Smart/RG or the R6900P using either the domain name or the IP address, it tries to log me in to the Smart/RG router's login page.

I can't figure out why I get the router's login page - if it's a setting on the Smart/RG, the R6900P, or the apache configuration on the webserver. Maybe it's some kind of race condition?

I realize this is a lot of information. Please ask any questions you have!

Answer (score 1):

> The Smart/RG uses 192.168.x.x, and the R6900P uses 10.0.x.x for
> internal addresses.

I suggest the following approach:

Change the Netgear Router to the subnet of the modem so it gets an IP on the same range as the main modem.

I would hook up a LAN port of the Netgear to the Ethernet port of the modem. Give the Netgear a static IP on the modem. Turn DHCP OFF on the Netgear router.

Now you have things on one subnet instead of two separate ones.

Also there may be a setting on the Wireless Router called "Wireless Isolation".   If so, disable Wireless Isolation.

That will facilitate redirecting to your websites when using wireless.